# Как в c#(WPF) перейти в другое окно не создавая нового окна?

Tags: c#, wpf

Например, возьмем установщик QT при нажатии далее появляется следующее окно
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Было бы неплохо показать небольшой пример как это сделать, либо ссылку где можно посмотреть/почитать об этом.